# How can I design an "invite friends" feature when my app is Android only?

Tags: android, invite, referrals, snapchat

This  might be a stupid question but I can't find the answer.

Snapchat and Instagram started as iOS only. How did they let you invite friends? Did they use the address book? What if I had an Android? Would I get a "Join me on Snapchat" invite, only to click a link and see "nah, you can't join"?

Background:
A friend and I have been working on an [Android productivity app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ninja.sesame.app).

We've got an idea for a social feature, it'd be a classic network effect. Users need to be able to invite friends from their address book. But we're Android only and don't have time to build a web or iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Firebase Invites` feature from Google: https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/

Comment: Thanks. Looks promising how they/google will recommend which contacts to use. I don't see the ability to filter to contacts that are on Android. I assume Google knows this. Am I missing it? Also, I asked a friend w/ a successful app and he said "you put that on the users"...